# Проблема с блоками в div

Tags: html, css

Должно получиться 2 блока по горизонтали(фото ниже), решил сделать сначала первый(левый) блок, потом второй(правый) но потом понял что так не получится, подскажите, как лучше сделать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>gorod</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="logo"><b>Black</b> + White</div>
            <div class="menu">
                <li><a href="$">home</a></li>
                <li><a href="$">our services</a></li>
                <li><a href="$">how we work</a></li>
                <li><a href="$">testimoniпals</a></li>
                <li><a href="$">work examples</a></li>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="block">
            <div class="img1">
                <div class="span">some slik pharase would go in here<br>to sup up what the business<br>actually does and stands for</div></div>
            <div class="img2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="excontainer">
            <div class="container1">
                <h1>services we offer</h1>
                <div class="line"></div>
                <p class="text1">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores deleniti porro corrupti consequuntur libero aperiam atque dolor error sit iure ullam, aspernatur deserunt nam consectetur aliquid fugit reiciendis qui exercitationem?</p>
                <p class="text2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur doloribus ipsum reiciendis enim cum aliquam quia placeat voluptates cumque ad amet doloremque, eos eveniet natus, totam voluptatibus, recusandae autem distinctio?</p>
                <button class="button">READ MORE</button>
            </div>
            <div class="container2">
                f
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@200&display=swap');

body{
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
  }

  
.container {
  width: 75%;
  height: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 40px;
  }
  
  .header {
    display: flex;
    height: 80px;
  }
  
  .logo {
    font-size: 35px;
  }
  
  .menu {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-left: 275px;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 45px;
    list-style: none;
    gap: 18px;
  }

  a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
}

a:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}


.block{
    display: flex;
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
}

.img1{
    font-size: 35px;
    color: aliceblue;
    height: 300px;
    width: 70%;
    background: url('/gorod/img/gorod.jpg');
    padding: 0px;
}


.img2{
    height: 300px;
    width: 30%;
    background-image: url('/gorod/img/img1.jpg');
    margin-left: 12px;
}

.span{
    background-color: black;
    font-size: 37px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    padding: 50px;
    text-shadow: 1px 3px 1px #000;
}


.container1{
  margin-top: 15px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 450px;
  height: 400px;
}


.line{
  border-bottom: 2px solid lightgray;
  width: 450px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}


.text1{
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  line-height: 22px;
}


.text2{
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  line-height: 22px;
}

.button{
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 10px;
}


.container2{
  display: inline-flex;
  margin-top: 15px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 450px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: В стилях `excontainer { display: flex;.......`

Comment: @Rudi казалось бы,такой легкий вопрос,как я так не додумался) тыкал флекс в .container1 и .container2